# Image View goes outside the containers such as VStack or ZStack even with frame widht and height set

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need to place an image with content mode 'Fill' in a VStack or ZStack.
But whenever i try this, the image goes outside the bounds.

This is the code in swiftUI

```
struct CategoryItem: View {
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        
        Image("s3")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .clipped()
            .padding(.all,8)
            
            
            
    }.frame(width: 100,height: 100)
        .background(.red)
    
}
```

}

This is what the issue i am facing, hope you get what i mean.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding that is being applied to the image makes this issue a bit harder to solve.

One way is to use a `GeometryReader` to find the size of the containing frame, then a smaller frame size can be applied to the image:

```swift
ZStack {
    Color.red
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        let w = proxy.size.width
        let h = proxy.size.height
        Image("s3")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: w - 16, height: h - 16)
            .clipped()
            .padding(8)
    }
}
.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
```

[image: Screenshot]

If the padding was just for example purposes and you don't actually need to pad the image, then all you need to do is move the `.clipped()` modifier so that it comes *after* the `.frame` modifier:

```swift
ZStack {
    Image("s3")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
}
.frame(width: 100,height: 100)
.clipped()
.background(.red)
```

[image: Screenshot]